# How to implement handshake mechanism between client and node (express) app for session timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am developing Agent application for customer support purpose.
Developed Routing app(backend-nodejs) and Agent app (front end -angular + nodejs).

**How things currently working is :**

1.agent logged in and ready to receive chat from Routing app.

2.Routing app sends the customer chat to  Agent app on socket(Invite) .

3.Agent app acknowledge to the request (send POST request on endpoint of Routing app) as I received your Invite and I accepted your invite.

4.then Routing app updates the status as Intercation is routed to xxx Agent.

**How I want to make above:**

1.agent logged in and ready to receive chat from Routing app.

2.Routing app sends the customer chat to  Agent app on socket(Invite).

3.Routing app should remember (add to session storage),It has sent invite to xxx Agent App for yyy session and should wait for acknowledgement from Agent app till 30 seconds .

4.1 first case :
If Routing app receives acknowledgement within 30 seconds then normal operation will go on.

4.2 second case :
If Routing app doesn't receives acknowledgement  within 30 seconds then it should forgot that it has sent invite for yyy session to xxx agent (delete it from his session storage) .and will try to reroute the customer to another available agent (for re-routing already functionality is defined so no need to consider this in current problem )

**Note** : storing the data in any db which Routing app has to remember while waiting for agent acknowledgement is prohibited .

Any help to implement this in node js would be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused on what you're asking. You've provided all the information you should need to do this, view your question as a set of instructions on what you need to do, take it step by step, this is good pseudocode to begin with.

Comment: @Finbar I have edited the question ,Hope it is now more understandable.
Thanks